# Confused about meaning of rule

Tags: normal-distribution, standardization, notation

What does this mean exactly?

[image]
[Image source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gnEXS.png)

I'm a bit confused about the part with z-score. It seems to be important when testing hypothesis.

Comment: What is the original source of this?

Answer (score 5):

The notation '$X_k \in N(\mu,\sigma)$' in your source means that the random variable $X_k$ has a [normal distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution) with mean $\mu$ and standard deviation $\sigma$. The second symbol in $N(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes the standard deviation, NOT the variance. This was brought to my attention by @Dilip Sarwate (see comment below).

It is more common to see the notation '$Y \sim N(u,\sigma^2)$' where the symbol '$\sim$' is prefered to '$\in$', which is more relevant to indicate membership of an element in a [set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory#Basic_concepts_and_notation), and where the second symbol in $N(\cdot,\cdot)$ denotes the variance. However, some softwares/programming languages also use standard deviation instead of variance as the second parameter (e.g. functions `[dpqr]norm` in R).

Comment: **No!!**  In the notation of the source, $N(\mu,\sigma)$ means a normal distribution with mean $\mu$ and **standard deviation** $\sigma$, _not variance_ $\sigma$ as you state. Note that the variance of the sum of $n$ independent identically distributed random variables with common variance $A$ (and stddev $\sqrt{A}$) is $nA$ while the standard deviation of the sum is $\sqrt{nA} = \sqrt{A}\cdot\sqrt{n} = \operatorname{stddev}\cdot\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: @Dilip Sarwate, thanks for spoting this! I've amended the answer accordingly.

Comment: I cannot see how $\sim$ could be equated with $\in$: the former names a *random variable* whose distribution is determined by a *particular* tuple of parameters $(u,\sigma^2)$ whereas the latter is a *generic* element of a set of *distributions*. I suppose you could (rigorously) write "$Y\in\{X|X\sim \mathcal{N}(u,\sigma^2)\}$"--but that even more clearly shows the distinction between $\sim$ ("has a distribution given by") and $\in$ ("is an element of").